# Alignment of variables in the .data section in NASM

Tags: assembly, optimization, memory, nasm, memory-alignment

Working with the output from Agner Fog's objconv, I see two instances of this comment:

```
; Note: Memory operand is misaligned. Performance penalty
```

That's solved by preceding the data declaration with ALIGN 16, e.g.:

```
section. data align=16
data_1: dq 0
data_2: dq 0
str_var: db "This is a string",0x00
ALIGN 16
MQX_Dcc: dq 0
```

My data section begins with align=16, but apparently that's not enough to prevent misalignment of some variables.

My questions are:

1. How can I know (without using a disassembler) that a memory operand is misaligned in the .data section?  I can count the number of bytes preceding the declaration, but that's tedious manually, especially when there are many declarations preceding the misaligned variable.
2. Would it be useful to precede every data declaration with an ALIGN directive?

Comment: The aligment request only aligns the beginning of the segment.  If you want to have a symbol aligned, you need to use a separate alignment directive before the symbol.  Normally I sort my variables to have variables of the same size next to each other so they are all aligned.  Then, only one alignment directive for a series of variables suffices.

Comment: Also, put string constants in `section .rodata` instead of read-write `.data`, so you have fewer pages that need to get COWed.

Comment: Both of the two comments above @fuz and Peter Cordes are good ideas.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At first, you should remove the typo in your first line: instead of

```
section. data align=16
```

it should be

```
section .data align=16
```

**Ad 1:** You can comfortably inspect offsets of all named memory operands by some tool which displays the symbol table. If you assembled you source to COFF for Windows, use

```
PEVIEW.EXE RTC222.obj
```

If it is assembled to ELF for Linux, use

```
readelf -s RTC222.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 7 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS RTC222.asm
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 data_1
     4: 0000000000000008     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 data_2
     5: 0000000000000010     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 str_var
     6: 0000000000000030     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 MQX_Dcc
```

Offsets of symbols are in the column Value.

**Ad 2:** No. As recommended by @fuz, put your memory variables in .data or .rodata section sorted by their alignment requirement in descending order (strings as the last). This will make the program shorter.